# How to solve this in Xcode error: no such file or directory: fishhook.c?

Tags: xcode, react-native, compiler-errors

I have React Native project. And at the moment i can not launch my IOS version, beacause i get this error: lang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/evgeniykireev/Desktop/poloapp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook/fishhook.c'. I have already tried many solutions but nothing is working for me. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had updated some dependencies, including react-native, and a library for onesignal. The error output showed that `fishook.h` was being referenced from some files in the `ios/build/<projectName>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator` folder, so I deleted the `ios/build` folder and rebuilt with no errors.